# Performance of text column update in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to store some potentially large log files in a text column in Postgres. And I would like to frequently append additional content to these files using an UPDATE statement. Will this be efficient?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE   mytable
SET      mytextlog = mytextlog || 'This will be appended'
WHERE    id = 1
```

Will Postgres simply append the additional content without rewriting what is in the column already? Or will it read the content of the column into memory, append the additional content, and then write back the entire column? I realize this is implementation detail. I'm just a little concerned that what I'm planning to do will be unnecessarily slow as the text being stored becomes large. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will rewrite the entire row unless the text get's compressed, then it's written to the TOAST table.

Comment: I guess you should rather keep a table of log lines, and just insert a new line there. Also makes queries easier.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thank you!